# Saying after rukoo

Tags: salat, allah

In islam, can women say “Rabbana walakalhamd hamdan katheeran tayyiban mubarakun fee” after rukoo?

Please answer

Comment: What do you mean exactly? And why shouldn't women say this after standing up from ruku'? Is there any difference between men and women in worship orders or why should they pray differently?

Comment: Because there is different stuff between men and women so i was just confused